# StructureMap in multi-layer solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

In my solution I have 3 projects: WebAPI, BusinessLayer and DataLayer.

In WebAPI I have structuremap configured to use a DefaultRegistry:

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry 
{
    public DefaultRegistry() 
    {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        For<Business.Interfaces.IBusinessClass>().Use(ctx => new Business.BusinessClass());
        For<Data.Interfaces.IDataClass>().Use(ctx => new Data.DataClass());            
    }
}
```

A controller class in WebAPI looks like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IBusinessClass _businessClass;

    public MyController(IBusinessClass businessClass)
    {
        _businessClass = businessClass;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var success = _businessClass.DoSomething();
        return success ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) :   Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error"); 
    }
}
```

Injecting dependency for _businessClass in this example works like a charm.

Now let's take a look at the BusinessClass implementation:

```
public class BusinessClass : IBusinessClass
{
    private readonly IDataClass _dataClass;

    public BusinessClass(IDataClass dataClass)
    {
        _dataClass = dataClass;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _dataClass.DoSomethingWithData();
    }
}
```

In this example dependency injection for _dataClass doesn't work. The dataClass param in the constructor is null so the _dataClass field isn't initialized properly. What am I doing wrong? 
I'll add that BusinessClass is defined in the BusinessLayer project and DataClass is defined in the DataLayer projects (both of those projects being class libraries).

Comment: How can it be that the line `ctx => new Data.DataClass()` compiles? Is there a second constructor that you aren't showing in your question?

Comment: It's just a simplification so the post isn't bloated with unnecessary code.

Comment: It appears that the problem is not with structuremap itself but with design of internal classes. Sorry for the hassle and thanks for trying to help. Case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you're default Registry you are already registering Default Conventions by calling

```
scan.WithDefaultConventions();
```

So these two calls are redundant.

```
For<Business.Interfaces.IBusinessClass>().Use(ctx => new Business.BusinessClass());
For<Data.Interfaces.IDataClass>().Use(ctx => new Data.DataClass());
```

Like Kenneth said you probably aren't scanning the assembly `BusinessClass` is located in.

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry 
{
    public DefaultRegistry() 
    {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.AssemblyContainingType<BusinessClass>();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your registration:

You're only scanning the calling assembly (which means the Web API project).

You need to include the other assemblies as well (you might need to adjust the names):

```
Scan(
        scan => {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.Assembly("BusinessLayer");
            scan.Assembly("DataLayer");
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
```

Comment: I tried scanning all the other assemblies in the DefaultRegistry but it didn't help. I might add that when I tried to use IDataClass/DataClass object in the WebAPI controller it worked fine. But when I tried using another class defined in business in the DoSomething() method, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem by use Singleton in StructureMap.